# Laravel Blade: Increment variable by 1 each time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Using Laravel blade template, is there a way to include a variable and increase each time in the foreach or what is better approach?

For example:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
  <li><a href="#tab_c1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

In the `foreach` block, the value from #tab_c1 will need to be increase. eg: `#tab_c1, #tab_c2, #tab_c3`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add iterator to `@foreach`:

```
@foreach($categories as $key => $category)
  <li @if ($key === 0) class="active" @endif>
    <a href="#tab_c{{$key+1}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      {{$category->name}}
    </a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

`{{$key+1}}` in my example because in PHP iterator starts at 0.

Comment: Thats great, thanks. Is there a way to include class="active" on the first <li> only?

Answer (score 30):

Since Laravel 5.3 you can use The Loop Variable, `$loop->iteration` for concrete situation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable

Example:

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
        <td>{{ $question->question }}</td>
        <td>{{ $question->category_id }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try this:

```
@php($count=0)

@foreach($unit->materials as $m)
    @if($m->type == "videos")
        @php($count++)
    @endif
@endforeach

{{$count}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Add a key value in the foreach loop

```
@foreach($questions as $key => $question)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ ++$key }}</th>
    <td>{{ $question->question }}</td>
    <td>{{ $question->category_id }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 10):

**Just use {{ $loop->iteration }} to iterate from 1 to limit**

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
  <li><a href="#tab_c{{ $loop->iteration }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use the key value. For most arrays that will just be 0 up.

```
@foreach($categories as $i => $category)
  <li{{ $i == 0 ? ' class="active"' : '' }}><a href="#tab_c{{ $i }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thats great, thanks. Is there a way to include `class="active"` on the first `<li>` only?

Comment: Sure, just use a ternary operator. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick
@php is same as php open and close tags in laravel

```
<?php $count=0; ?>
 @php($count=0)

<table>
<th>#</th>
<th>Category Name</th>
<tbody>
@php($count=0)
@foreach($categories as $category)
@php($count++)
<tr>
<td>{{$count}}</td>
<td>{{$category->name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your solution (e.g. explain what the trick is, what the @php function does, etc...)